# In javers, can you add additional entries

Tags: java, javers

When taking a snapshot of a particular entity, apart from timestamp, user who did the change, etc, I would like to add an additional custom field (ex: comment, which is not described in the entity). Is it possible with Javers when using the auto-audit feature? If yes how can you do it and if no are there any plans of including it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, the properties get added to jv_commit_property table.  For example:

```
Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("comment", "My custom comment");
javers.commit("Some name", myChangedObject, params);
```

Comment: is this supported in auto-audit? ie when annotating CRUD Repositories with @JaversSpringDataAuditable.

Comment: Looking at the [code for that annotation](https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-spring/src/main/java/org/javers/spring/annotation), there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this.  In any case it would only allow you to add static params to the commits

Comment: https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/375 is done & released in JaVers 2.0.0-RC2